# Parse ISO 8583 and put it in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, jpos

Hi I'm in the process of monitoring the application log containing ISO 8583. And I want the ISO message to be parsed and display it in elasticsearch. I've tried using grok, but that's not possible because there are several different counts in each log, so it requires parsing using another application.

My question now is, is it possible to parse using an application outside of logstash and put it back into logstash and send it to elasticsearch? How? Here I try to use a Java application using the JPOS library.

[This is the result of combining ISO 5853 from raw logs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awATd.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you mean with "ISO 8583" what I think that you mean, then this should not be written to a "log". Although I confess that using (or abusing) the infrastructure that was created for logging analysis also for the analysis of audit trails makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if possible, you need to parse the message before inserting to logtash. I have solved it like this for splunk, elk and opensearch. this is the opening of your message.

Comment: Please keep all contact within Stack Overflow. Also, consider that email address burned, as every spam-scraper will already have gotten hold of it